# How can I completely delete a user in Windows via the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, user-accounts, active-directory

There is a user **Alice** that logged in a lot of windows machine using your AD account. In every computer, the windows create the user's files like: `c:\users\alice`

Now I want to complete remove this user in all computers. I could use the windows system in every computer and do it manually with `Settings->Accounts`. But this is slow.

I could just delete the folder `c:\users\alice`. But I think a lot of trash from this user will be in the computer (not the files, I mean entries in the registry and others).

##### How can I completely delete a user in Windows via the command line?

Comment: I will undelete it because someone can search it. But the answer is in the duplicate question.